# How can I make Ubuntu 16.04 tell that my connection to internet is limited

Tags: wireless, internet, 16.04, gui, lan

Since last few days I'm facing connectivity issues as my service provider is changing the fibre cables. As a result, my connection keeps toggling between " connected" and "Connected but No Internet".

Windows 10 and my Android phone show me with different icon and messages for both of the states . Here are the screenshots for limited connection on

**Windows**

Please see how my WiFi icon is replaced with the yellow exclamation sign , and how the message was changed to "*No internet,secured*".

[image: windows connection screen with limited connection message]

**Android Device**

Please see how my WiFi icon is replaced with the exclamation sign , and how the message was changed to "*Connected ,No internet*".

[image]

[image]

**But on Ubuntu 16.04**

It remains same for both of the cases. There is no change at all.

[image]

How can I make Ubuntu display different messages and icon for these two different cases ?